# Error from aggregate function from the R package sf

Tags: r, sf, stars

I am currently reading the new (and free!) book by Edzer Pebesma and Roger Bivand (you can find it [here](https://keen-swartz-3146c4.netlify.com/)).

In chapter four they describe how one can aggregate all the measurement stations within one state. I follow there code but get an error. How so?

```
library(sf)
library(spacetime)
library(rgeos)
library(stars)
# dataset from spacetime package
data(air)
d = st_dimensions(station = st_as_sfc(stations), time = dates)
aq = st_as_stars(list(PM10 = air), dimensions = d)
a = aggregate(aq, st_as_sf(DE_NUTS1), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The last line returns the error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
Arguments must have same length
```

Comment: Have you already seen this article [Error in aggregate.data.frame : arguments must have same length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325922/error-in-aggregate-data-frame-arguments-must-have-same-length) ?

Comment: Where does st_dimensions and st_as_stars come from? The latest CRAN versions of sf, spacetime, and rgeos do not have them.

Comment: @ Taras No, thanks I had not seen that, but it also does not help me further. @Spacedman Sorry for that. They are both from the stars package. Forgot to include that. I installed all the packages in the last week so they are most likely up to date. Versions: sf: 0.7-2, rgeos 0.4-2, spacetime 1.2-2 and stars 0.2-0.

Comment: Perhaps `aggregate` method for `stars` objects will become available in the next version, stars 0.3-0.

Comment: Hi JonJup `stars 0.3-0` is now on CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `aggregate` method is supported by `methods()`.

```
# stars 0.2-0
> library(stars)
> methods(class= "stars")
 [1] [              [<-            adrop          aperm          as.data.frame  c              coerce        
 [8] cut            dim            dimnames       dimnames<-     filter         image          initialize    
[15] is.na          Math           merge          Ops            plot           print          show          
[22] slotsFromS3    split          st_apply       st_as_sf       st_as_sfc      st_as_stars    st_bbox       
[29] st_coordinates st_crop        st_crs         st_crs<-       st_dimensions  st_transform   st_write
```

Ta-da! `stars 0.3-0` is on CRAN today (25/FEB/2019).

```
# stars 0.3-0
> library(stars)
> methods(class= "stars")
 [1] $<-            [              [<-            adrop          aggregate      aperm         
 [7] as.data.frame  c              coerce         cut            dim            dimnames      
[13] dimnames<-     image          initialize     is.na          Math           merge         
[19] Ops            plot           print          show           slotsFromS3    split         
[25] st_apply       st_area        st_as_sf       st_as_sfc      st_as_stars    st_bbox       
[31] st_coordinates st_crop        st_crs         st_crs<-       st_dimensions  st_geometry   
[37] st_redimension st_transform   write_stars
```

You can see `aggreagte` is listed. Yay!

---

By the way, if you add `tidyverse`, the list expands like:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(stars)
> methods(class= "stars")
 [1] $<-            [              [<-            adrop          aggregate      aperm         
 [7] as.data.frame  as.tbl_cube    c              coerce         cut            dim           
[13] dimnames       dimnames<-     filter         image          initialize     is.na         
[19] Math           merge          mutate         Ops            plot           print         
[25] pull           select         show           slice          slotsFromS3    split         
[31] st_apply       st_area        st_as_sf       st_as_sfc      st_as_stars    st_bbox       
[37] st_coordinates st_crop        st_crs         st_crs<-       st_dimensions  st_geometry   
[43] st_redimension st_transform   write_stars
```

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks a lot. Looks like the content of the book was ahead of the released package version.

Comment: @JonJup It will be nice if you create a new tag `stars` for us. I imagine it will soon become a popular tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot create new tags yet. My reputation is too low.

Comment: Thanks @JonJup and sorry I did not know that. Let me give it a try.